# Remove data function using javascript only works once

Tags: javascript, html, css, row

new to JS here. The below code works fine for summing up the totaldonation value using the donate button but why does the the **remove** button function only updates the *totaldonation* value once. then it just removes the row without updating the *totaldonation* value. Been looking everywhere for answers and really need some help. Thanks

**Code**

```js
var totaldonation = 0;
var totalprice = 0;
var x = document.getElementById("totaldonation");

function addHtmlTableRow(ele) {
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

  var elitem = ele.closest('.item');
  var quantity = elitem.querySelector(".quantity").value;
  var itemprice = elitem.querySelector(".itemprice").value;
  var itemname = elitem.querySelector('.itemname').value;
  totalprice = itemprice * quantity;

  cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

  cell1.innerHTML = itemname;
  cell2.innerHTML = quantity;
  cell3.innerHTML = itemprice;
  cell4.innerHTML = totalprice;

  totaldonation = totaldonation + totalprice;

  var removeBtn = document.createElement("input");
  removeBtn.type = "button";
  removeBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Remove');
  removeBtn.setAttribute('class', 'removeBtn');
  removeBtn.setAttribute('id', 'removeBtn');
  removeBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteData(this,totaldonation,totalprice)');
  cell4.appendChild(removeBtn);

  x.innerHTML = totaldonation;
}

function deleteData(btn, totaldonation, totalprice) {
  totaldonation = totaldonation - totalprice;
  x.innerHTML = totaldonation;
  $(btn).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item active">
  <img src="item/dapur.png" class="img-responsive" style="height:120px;">
  <input class="input-display itemname" type="text" id="itemname1" value="Dapur" readonly>
  <b><input class="input-display itemprice" type="text" id="itemprice1" 
    value="30" readonly></b>
  <input class="form-control quantity" type="number" id="quantity1">
  <button class="btn default" value="1" onclick="addHtmlTableRow(this);">Donate</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="item/dapur.png" class="img-responsive" style="height:120px;">
  <input class="input-display itemname" type="text" id="itemname2" value="Dapur" readonly>
  <b><input class="input-display itemprice" type="text" id="itemprice2" 
     value="10" readonly></b>
  <input class="form-control quantity" type="number" id="quantity2">
  <button class="btn default" value="2" onclick="addHtmlTableRow(this);">Donate</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="item/dapur.png" class="img-responsive" style="height:120px;">
  <input class="input-display itemname" type="text" id="itemname3" value="Dapur" readonly>
  <b><input class="input-display itemprice" type="text" id="itemprice3" 
    value="20" readonly></b>
  <input class="form-control quantity" type="number" id="quantity3">
  <button class="btn default" value="3" onclick="addHtmlTableRow(this);">Donate</button>
</div>


<table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price per unit</th>
      <th>Total price Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="totaldonation"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the values of the global variables `totaldonation` and `totalprice` to the `deleteData()` function. `totalprice` always contains the amount from the last donation you made, not the donation for the row you're deleting.

Also, since you're using `totaldonation` as a function parameter, you're updating the local variable, not the global variable when you assign to it. You need to learn about variable scopes (and you should declare all the temporary variables, like `cell1`, as local variables).

It would be best for `deleteData()` to get the amount to subtract from the current table row, not a function parameter.

```js
var totaldonation = 0;
var x = document.getElementById("totaldonation");

function addHtmlTableRow(ele) {
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

  var elitem = ele.closest('.item');
  var quantity = elitem.querySelector(".quantity").value;
  var itemprice = elitem.querySelector(".itemprice").value;
  var itemname = elitem.querySelector('.itemname').value;
  var totalprice = itemprice * quantity;

  var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

  cell1.innerHTML = itemname;
  cell2.innerHTML = quantity;
  cell3.innerHTML = itemprice;
  cell4.innerHTML = totalprice;

  totaldonation = totaldonation + totalprice;

  var removeBtn = document.createElement("input");
  removeBtn.type = "button";
  removeBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Remove');
  removeBtn.setAttribute('class', 'removeBtn');
  removeBtn.setAttribute('id', 'removeBtn');
  removeBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteData(this)');
  cell4.appendChild(removeBtn);

  x.innerHTML = totaldonation;
}

function deleteData(btn) {
  let totalprice = parseInt($(btn).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(4)").html());
  totaldonation = totaldonation - totalprice;
  x.innerHTML = totaldonation;
  $(btn).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item active">
  <img src="item/dapur.png" class="img-responsive" style="height:120px;">
  <input class="input-display itemname" type="text" id="itemname1" value="Dapur" readonly>
  <b><input class="input-display itemprice" type="text" id="itemprice1" 
    value="30" readonly></b>
  <input class="form-control quantity" type="number" id="quantity1">
  <button class="btn default" value="1" onclick="addHtmlTableRow(this);">Donate</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="item/dapur.png" class="img-responsive" style="height:120px;">
  <input class="input-display itemname" type="text" id="itemname2" value="Dapur" readonly>
  <b><input class="input-display itemprice" type="text" id="itemprice2" 
     value="10" readonly></b>
  <input class="form-control quantity" type="number" id="quantity2">
  <button class="btn default" value="2" onclick="addHtmlTableRow(this);">Donate</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="item/dapur.png" class="img-responsive" style="height:120px;">
  <input class="input-display itemname" type="text" id="itemname3" value="Dapur" readonly>
  <b><input class="input-display itemprice" type="text" id="itemprice3" 
    value="20" readonly></b>
  <input class="form-control quantity" type="number" id="quantity3">
  <button class="btn default" value="3" onclick="addHtmlTableRow(this);">Donate</button>
</div>


<table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price per unit</th>
      <th>Total price Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="totaldonation"></div>
```